# Can I use ILM for deleting indices which are old and do not belong to an alias

Tags: elasticsearch, ilm

I am looking for a way to periodically clean up Elastic search indices which are older than X days and do not belong to an alias.
I know that ILM can be used for "older than" part, but is it possible to also configure it somehow so it can check and only delete those which do not belong to an alias?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, there's no specific check to do that sorry to say as the assumption is that they will be attached to an ILM policy with an alias